# Negative growing ping on win machines

Tags: windows-xp, ping

I'm having a WAN with several machines connected from a different country. All machines run win xp and while testing network it appeared that ping shows negative/positive and is constantly growing.

What can be wrong with it and which God could have made a negative ping out there (I'll have a chat with him ;))?

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** It's a WinXP machines running on Intel Core2 Quad (not sure which one) processor.

Comment: How does those machine connect to your network? VPN?

Comment: @Vick Vegar, network is up by just plugging a cable, which in turn goes through a other devices, probably switch and elsewhere (I'm not sure about detailed connection paths).

Comment: @den-javamaniac, Please clarify, those windows xp computers connect to your network over the WAN and when you ping local systems FROM those computers you're getting negative ping results?

Comment: @Vick Vega, exactly. Over time ping grows (takes about half an hour to see the actual growth). Interesting thing is that I'm testing the connection using ubuntu LiveCD and it looks like ping is generally stable (fixed timing range).

Comment: @den-javamaniac, It's kinda hit and miss situation, quite broad topic to troubleshoot. Here is what you can start with: 1. Identify exact way those computers connect between each other. 2. Validate exactly in what situations that's happening. 3. Verify is there're any specific policies apply to those machines, either from network point of view or from AD, if you have one.

Comment: What is a negative ping? How does the ping go "negative/positive" exactly?

Comment: @joeqwerty, Ping info looks like next: Reply from *PINGED_IP_HERE* bytes=32 time=-23ms TTL=64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install win7 or ubuntu 10.x. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem with your computer. Ping times are based on processor timings, which should always move forward.

If you're running an AMD processor, then here's one guy's experience trying to fix it: http://wiki.ljackson.us/Negative_Ping_Time

The answer generally seems to be updating your CPU driver from AMD.

Comment: I actually tried google fu, but no one seem to complain about Intel based stuff. Thanx for answer, though.